# Change Content On Click Using Numbers?

Tags: jquery

**Change Content On Click**

I'm trying to change content on click (like RokSprocket, but static). I'm doing this by using corresponding numbers.

What I haven't figured out is how to turn `_17` into whichever number gets clicked (maybe getElementByClassName?), and how to make the second part "(any other number) / _#" the numbers that weren't clicked

*the class `_17` is just an example. I don't plan on going that high, but just in case I do*

**jQuery:**

```
$(".nav-tabs > _17").click(function() {
    if($(".content > _17").hasClass("hidden")) {
    $(".content > _17").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".content > _17").addClass("visible");

    if($(".content > (any number but the one clicked)").hasClass("visible")) {
    $(".content > _#").removeClass("visible");
    $(".content > _#").addClass("hidden");
}
```

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/44athvvL/1/

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I showed my code, provided what I've tried so far, and added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/06tk2pcv/).

I'm not sure if you are really required to use classes to identify corresponding elements, also, I'm not sure if those are the only class you will assign to the `li`s that will contain an underscore in the class name. But assuming those, I checked the classes of the clicked element for the pattern '_#' using regexp and then extracting the number using `.split()`

**JS**

```
$(".nav-tabs > li").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        classes = $this.attr('class').toString().split(/s+/),
        num = 0;

    $.each(classes, function (i, v) {
        if (v.match(/_\d+/gim).length) num = v.split('_')[1];
    });

    $('._' + num)
        .removeClass('hidden')
        .addClass('visible');

    $('div').not('._' + num)
        .removeClass('visible')
        .addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ran into one issue, it only worked the first time I clicked the list items. I added 4 lines of jquery, a separate `addClass` `removeClass` for the list-items, but it's 100% now :) Thanks again for all your help! **Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/06tk2pcv/1/